# What port to open for mail/postfix server outbound AWS ecs2

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I have an EC2 running Ubuntu with Kafka installed, I've installed mailutils on the server because I have a script monitoring diskspace on the box and to email me when it reaches a certain threshold eg: `80%`.

The Kafka server I've locked down to internal use, if I open all the ports on my outbound security group I can receive the warning from the script to my email.

I would like to lock this down to a port number on my outbound security group but can't seem to do it, I've tried ports `465` and `587`. I have looked around online but nothing I found to do what I need, does anyone know what port it is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What ports to open for mail server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/149903/what-ports-to-open-for-mail-server)

Comment: Not sure why it a duplicate, mine is to do with AWS EC2 security group. Should I edit the title more?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Does Postfix use the destination ports as the outbound ports?

Comment: @Paul SMTP servers will usually connect to other servers on port 25, if that's what you mean. Because SMTP servers listen on that port.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin I read his question as configuring outbound ports, which are usually not the same as destination ports.

Comment: @Paul Source ports I think you mean are usually chosen by the OS and don't mean much. Outbound port = destination port. I don't believe there is anything in Postfix to configure the source port, but I haven't bothered to check. It isn't an issue. I believe there would be many source ports, one for each outbound connection (which can be a lot on a busy server). It's not really an SMTP or Postfix specific concept.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Some firewalls are configured to prevent anything from connecting to the Internet without specific allow rules, in which case it would be an issue. I may have the terminology wrong, but I do understand that most source ports are chosen randomly within a defined range by most tools.

Comment: @Paul Really off topic here.. TCP/Firewalls 101

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for TCP **port 25**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

> SMTP by default uses TCP port 25. The protocol for mail submission is
>   the same, but uses port 587. SMTP connections secured by SSL, known as
>   SMTPS, default to port 465 (nonstandard, but sometimes used for legacy
>   reasons).

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/149903/what-ports-to-open-for-mail-server?rq=1

Comment: Why duplicate, this is specific to AWS EC2

Comment: @Gman Not really. AWS has a firewall... this is about opening ports in a firewall. AWS/pfSense/iptables... makes no difference, it's the same answer, same issue.

Comment: I will remove the question then

Comment: @Gman You don't need to do that (unless you want to). Your question hasn't been voted closed, which means not enough people agree with my opinion that this is a duplicate. Also, if the answer doesn't work and there is some EC2 specific problem to resolve, you can update your question and get help. I'll retract my vote/comments in that case. Did you try allowing port 25?

Comment: yes and it works 100%