# Possible to host own SMTP server without port 25 open

Tags: smtp

I have a VPS on Digitalocean and Hetzner, but both block port 25, so I cannot host my own SMTP server here. However port 587 is open, so my question is: Is it possible to host your own standalone SMTP server, when port 25 is blocked, so it uses port 587 instead?

Comment: I've had a server in Hetzner and hosted a mail server there with 30+ virtual domains for 10+ years. Since when they start blocking port 25? Or probably they only block it for VPSs? Or this is invalid https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/postfix-as-SMTP-relay-server ? Probably, you can request unblock? Also, do they block incoming requests to your port 25, or outgoing requests to other's ports 25, or both?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What ports to open for mail server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/149903/what-ports-to-open-for-mail-server)

Answer (score 0):

It will work as long as you don't want to transact with other servers using RFC standards for purposes of sending or receiving email.